# how to sum in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

I have the data I'm querying

```
total_a | total_b | sum |
1200       500       ?
```

this my query

```
select 
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN status= 0 THEN total_budget ELSE 0 END)) AS total_a,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN status= 1  THEN total_sisa_tahun_lalu ELSE 0 END)) AS total_b,
    SUM(COALESCE(total_a,0) + COALESCE(total_b,0))
from product
```

my query didn't succeed in summing the alias alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference a column alias in the `SELECT` where it is defined.  The reason is simple:  SQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`.

You can use a CTE, subquery, or repeat the expression:

```
select ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN status= 0 THEN total_budget ELSE 0 END)) AS total_a,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN status= 1  THEN total_sisa_tahun_lalu ELSE 0 END)) AS total_b,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN total_budget
                WHEN status = 1 THEN total_sisa_tahun_lalu
                ELSE 0
           END)
from product
```